# Is there a way to change the complete URL of the blog post for a redirecting tracking link?

Tags: posts, permalinks

Client wants to add tracking URLs to each blog post.

So, for example, he gave me a URL like `http://clk.atdmt.com/CNT/go/1234567/01/` which when clicked on would redirect to the URL of the blog post.

I know that I can change the permalink on the Edit Post screen, but I can't change the site domain.

Is there any way I can insert the tracking URL to replace the URL that WordPress generates?

Comment: @G.M. Yes, for example, I just tried the plugin "Page Links To" which allowed me to enter in a custom URL for the blog post. However, this doesn't work for my situation because the plugin changes the URL of the blog post entirely. I want to keep the blog post URL, but just add a redirect link if possible.

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong or maybe I'm still confused, but I tried using jQuery to change the URL of the blog post like this: `$('#post-1 h1 a').attr('href', 'http://clk.atdmt.com/CNT/go/1234567/01/');` and it seemed to work.

Comment: Yes, it sends me to that link but that link is a redirect to the actual url of the blog post. The 'Page Links To' plugin changes the url of the blog post entirely.

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand. What is not clear is if tracking url is unique or there is a tracking back for every post. If the tracking url is unique how do the tracking system know to which post redirect back users? If tracking url change for every post, there is a relation between tracking url and original post url (or maybe post id)?

Comment: There is a separate tracking URL for each blog post. There will only be five or so posts so not many tracking URLs total. Basically, each blog post will be set up with a standard title (e.g. news-post-1, news-post-2, etc.) which will each have its own tracking URL provided by the client.